# Angular 1.5.4 $http progress event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, progress

Now Angular 1.5.4 finally allows you to track progress event on $http provider but for some reason I keep getting the $rootScope as a response instead of an actual progress (I'm using it for uploads) information. Because of lack of examples I found some tests in the Angular repo and followed that but to no success.

```
restClientInstance.post = function (requestParams) {
    var postParams = {
        method: "POST",
        url: API_URL + requestParams.url,
        headers: requestParams.headers,
        data: requestParams.data,
        eventHandlers: {
            progress: function (c) {
                console.log(c);
            }
        },
        uploadEventHandlers: {
            progress: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    };

    var promise = $http(postParams)
    $rootScope.$apply();
    return promise;
};
```

In both cases it consoles $rootScope rather than the *lengthComputable*

Comment: the answer using pure angular:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41930083/2179157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up doing something like this and just handle it myself as the XHR events added to $http dont work for me.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var promise = $q.defer();

xhttp.upload.addEventListener("progress",function (e) {
    promise.notify(e);
});
xhttp.upload.addEventListener("load",function (e) {
    promise.resolve(e);
});
xhttp.upload.addEventListener("error",function (e) {
    promise.reject(e);
});

xhttp.open("post",API_URL + requestParams.url,true);

xhttp.send(requestParams.data);

return promise.promise;
```

Comment: The progress updates as it should and all works as it should I think 1.5.4 is just buggy at the moment.

Comment: It's a shame that this isn't wired up correctly in the $http APIs.

Comment: curious, have you gone to the 1.5.4 github page and reported an issue?

Comment: @jusopi maybe it is and I just am doing something wrong?

Comment: @jusopi yes I reported it on their page.

Answer (score 14):

In AngularJS v1.5.7 works fine. If you have the chance I recommend upgrade!

```
...//formData = new FormData(); etc...
var postParams = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: yourURLWS,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function (e) {
                  if (e.lengthComputable) {
                     $scope.progressBar = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                     $scope.progressCounter = $scope.progressBar;
                  }
        }
    },
    data: formData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined }
};

var sendPost = $http(postParams); //etc...
```

in HTML you have:

```
<progress id="progress" max="100" value="{{progressBar}}"></progress>{{progressCounter}}%
```

Result:

[progress result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPI45.png)

Comment: Another way is `$http.post(yourURLWS, formData, postParams)` (without the redundancy)

Comment: I have 100% immediately after sending request despite that a file loading isn't complete.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is broken for now: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14436

Answer (score 1):

**note** - *I have not worked with NG 1.5.4, the example below is for leveraging existing pre 1.5.4 APIs*

---

The `notify(event)` API is part of the *deferred* object when you call `$q.defer()`.  I'm not sure what a  practical implementation of this would be in terms of a typical *get/put/post* call via `$http`.  But if you want to see it in action you can do something like this:

**some service API**

```
var mockRqst = function(){
    var d = $q.defer()
    var crnt = 0

    $off = $interval( function(){
        d.notify( crnt )
        crnt += 5

        if (crnt >= 100)
        {
            $interval.cancel( $off ) //cancel the interval callback
            d.resolve( "complete" )
        }
    }

    return d.promise
}
```

**using the notification**

```
someService.mockRqst()
.then( thenCallback, catchCallback, function( update ){
     console.log("update", update)
})
```

*codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/eZMjrK?editors=1010*

Again, I must stress that I'm not entirely sure how you can tie this into an actual external http call.

Comment: See angular 1.5.4 (which has been released like a day ago or so) finally adds the event listeners to $http call that you can bind to underlying XHR so you can listen to xhr.progress and xhr.upload.progress but here's my problem when I created my own upload request using plain JS onprogress returns nicely all info about the file but the implementation in Angular 1.5.4 returns me $rootScope where it should the event.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api), the third parameter in a promise is a `notify` function.

> `notify(value)` - provides updates on the status of the promise's execution. This may be called multiple times before the promise is either resolved or rejected.

It can be used like this:

```
$http(requestData)
    .then(
        function success() {
            console.log('success');
        },
        function error() {
            console.log('error');
        },
        function notify() {
            console.log('notified');
        }
    );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure notify actually never fires.

Comment: Strange, I have notify working in my own app, could you put some code in a fiddle ?

Comment: For $http? or is it your own promise wrapper for XHR?

Comment: @DupliaApp `$http`, it's even in the `$q` documentation

Comment: Oh also I didnt mention its the file upload progress not just a request progress.

Comment: Well the documentation never actually goes to show you an example with the notification I'm pretty sure this has never worked with file uploads.