# How can I retrieve page loading percentage value with angularjs on account of $http rest service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I actually need to implement something like the below template.

[image: That load spinner is possible with ng-show and ng-hide of loading.gif incase of not needing percentage but I need percentage of load to.]

That load spinner alone is possible with ng-show and ng-hide of loading.gif incase of not needing percentage but I need percentage of load too on account of start and completion of $http rest service.

Comment: I see the jquery tag. if so, you could make use of the progress-events of xmlhttprequest2 object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 1.5.4 $http progress event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622826/angular-1-5-4-http-progress-event)

Answer (score 2):

One way I see this is through `jQuery`'s  [jquery.ajax.progress.js](https://gist.github.com/db/966388#file-jquery-ajax-progress-js-L24)

The code to print progress in console is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./json.js",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function() { console.log("Completed."); },
    progress: function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("Loaded " + parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Length not computable.");
        }
    }

});
```

See this [github](https://gist.github.com/db/966388) page for more info.

Comment: When I tried 
$http.get(url).progress(function(evt){
 console.log("Loaded " + parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");
});
I received error like '$http.(..).progress() isnot a function.

Comment: you can't use `.progress()` on `$http`. Understand the difference. `$.ajax` is jQuery code and `$http` is `angularjs`'s object. BOTH ARE DIFFERENT.