# How to get $http readyState on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

How can I get $http readyState, use like this:

```
var request, interval;

request = $http
  .post('/user/info', {...})
  .success(...);

interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(request.readyState < 3)
    return;

  prepare(request.data, request.headers);
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10);

function prepare(data, headers){
  ...
}
```

I have no idea how to do this without changing the angular.js file. Is it possible add some features to the service via $httpBackend or something other?

Comment: What do you want to achive? What is the goal for this?

Comment: `var request` is a promise. It does not return value. after it is resolved you can use the value it returns.

Comment: @Vitalii actually, for many goals. For example, accurate download progress bar, comparing received content with "Content-length" header, processing of some unclosed connections, traffic optimization via search from received content, etc.

Comment: @DragonKnight that's why I ask: is there some way to solve this?

Comment: you have to write your code in success function. put log and inside and outside your success function. youll get your answer.

Comment: @DragonKnight you didn't understand, I need to handle `$http` request BEFORE when `readyState` be = 4

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622826/angular-1-5-4-http-progress-event

Comment: @Vitalii hmm, just looked at "uploadEventHandlers", is good, but not solve all problems, because there are many places where need watch to `$http readyState` and do something when readyState = N

Comment: Create an obesrver  as a service and notify subscribers.

Comment: @Vitalii yeah, but how can I watch the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: You don't need to do this. If you need global watch - create an httpService that will always pass uploadEventHandlers and notify subscribers. If you need local watch - make this handler passable as a param to $httpService and thats all.

Comment: @Vitalii yeah, I understand, so there is my question: how to do that?

Comment: Use the `eventHandlers` property of the config object to add an event handler that gets the [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) readyState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [AngularJS 1.5.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), support was added for additional handling of [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) events:

> ### $http Arguments - Config
>
> Object describing the request to be made and how it should be processed. The object has following properties:
>
> - **eventHandlers** - `{Object}` - Event listeners to be bound to the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). To bind events to the `XMLHttpRequest` upload object, use `uploadEventHandlers`. The handler will be called in the context of a `$apply` block.
> - **uploadEventHandlers** - `{Object}` - Event listeners to be bound to the XMLHttpRequest [upload object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload). To bind events to the `XMLHttpRequest` object, use eventHandlers. The handler will be called in the context of a `$apply` block.
>
> [— AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Http Arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments)

Use the `eventHandlers` property of the config object to add an event handller that gets the [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) `readyState`:

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/x6rcmw0O2mmsW8Fc2Kx2?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($rootScope, $http){
  var eventHandlers = {readystatechange: readyStateChangeHandler};
  var config = { eventHandlers: eventHandlers }; 
  $rootScope.messageList = [];
  
  function readyStateChangeHandler(ev) {
    var message = "readyState: "+ev.target.readyState;
    console.log(message);
    $rootScope.messageList.push(message);
  }
  
  $http.get("//httpbin.org/anything",config)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log("OK");
      //console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(response){
      console.log("ERROR");
      //console.log(response); 
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-repeat="m in messageList">
      {{m}}  
    </div>
  </body>
```