# Rewrite URL using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am new to angularJS , i am trying to redirect my Drupal App to a page within my app thats created using AngularJS

Now on my Drupal side i have a link as follows
http://localhost/drupal6/sites/all/themes/platinum_printing/js/extjs/angular/views/system_text_response.html

But i want my routes to rename it to some thing like this

http://localhost/drupal6/text_response

I tried to do something like this in my `app.js`

```
$routeProvider.when('http://localhost/drupal6/sites/all/themes/platinum_printing/js/extjs/angular/views/system_text_response.html', {
        controller: "SystemTextResponseController",
        templateUrl: "/sites/all/themes/platinum_printing/js/extjs/angular/views/system_text_response.html"
        url: "/text_response",
    });
```

But i am unable to do this. This is a total noobish question but then again i am new to AngularJS

Comment: Can you please check [Angular 1.5.4 $http progress event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576662/2435473)

Comment: Why don't you apply a redirect in yours .httaccess to your new app?

Comment: I think you need to provide some more information. Is the "drupal6/sites/all/themes/platinum_printing/js/extjs/angular/views/" part of the URL generated by Drupal? If so, there is very little Angular can do here. Angular routing normally takes place after the #.  You can drop the # but I am not sure if that is what you are doing here. Instructions on how to do this can be found here:- http://blog.theodo.fr/2017/01/pretty-url-in-angularjs-and-loopback-drop-the/