# Angularjs $http and progress bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar

I need to upload file and I use $http (this code is get from my .service() function):

```
sendFile: function (params) {
            return $http({method : 'post',
                url : 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/rest/file.json',
                headers : { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $cookies['csrftoken']},
                data : params
            })
        },
```

Now, for little file and a good line there is no problem, but with a big file and/or a bad/slow line there is a problem of UI: user can not know when upload will be end. I need a progress bar.

So I have search on internet, but I have not found a solution. Is there a possibility to get some progress/notification from $http ?

I have tried this code without luck:

```
ProfileService.sendFile(data)
                    .then(function(ret) {
                            var uri = ret.data.uri;
                            scope.content = "Upload finished";

                            scope.postForm.fid = ret.data.fid;
                            scope.postForm.buttonDisabled = false;
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            scope.postForm.showError = true;
                            scope.postForm.errorMsg = error.data;
                        },
                        function(progress) {
                            console.log("inside progress");
                            console.log(progress)
                        }
                    );
```

“progress” function is never called.

I'm using angular 1.2.x

Thanks.

Comment: you can probably use you buttonDisabled boolean to show/hide a loading gif and that would take care of your problem

Comment: Thanks, but "loading" is not "progress". I want to show to my user where the upload is.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have kind of the same problem. I am trying to get upload progress info from http request but I have not found any. All of the answers below are talking about the UI aspect but not the actual work behind it.

Answer (score 51):

You can use [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/). It works automatically for `$http` requests and does not need any setup except adding it as app dependency.

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-loading-bar']); // that's all
```

Comment: I just added **angular-loading-bar** and it's awesome :D Tiny, easy to integrate and fully customisable :)

Comment: This does not actually track the file upload at all, interesting that a lot of people upvoted !!!! The code at line 255 describes it /**
       * Increments the loading bar by a random amount
       * but slows down as it progresses
       */

Comment: This is the only plugin that is actually helpful rest answers are just experimental on this topic.

Comment: It seemed to reported an incorrect percentage when I uploaded a file (as a base64 string)

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend ng-progress. This handles multiple requests and basically shows a neat little progress bar for all http activity.

http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/

Comment: I need to get "progress" from $http before I can use ngProgress. So, how can I get "progress" from $http ?

Comment: @mithun_daa No, ngProgress doesn;t implement any $http interceptor. As far as I know, the $q promise api doesn't give any information about the download progress of a request. 
This thread gives some insights : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934

Comment: @Cooluhuru My bad, I was thinking nProgress not ngProgress. nProgress does hook into the interceptors.

Comment: http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/# -- anotehr option that uses inteceptors.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by hiding/showing a loadingbar. Start showing the loadingbar once the upload starts, and remove the loadingbar when the upload is done (in the *success handler* from the *$http request*).

I created a simple jsfiddle for you to show you an example.
*I'm using `$timeout` to simulate a `$http` request.*

Html markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <!-- this can be an image if you want -->
    <p ng-show="loading">...LOADING...</p>

    <!-- Showing the status -->
    <p ng-hide="loading">{{status}}</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="upload()">Do $http request</button>
</div>
```

Js Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.status = 'Not started';
    $scope.loading = false;

    $scope.upload = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        // Simulating a http request with a timeout
        $timeout(function(){ 
            $scope.status = "Finished";
            $scope.loading = false;
        },3000);
    }
}
```

For a demonstration of how this works, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GA9t8/2/).

**Update**

By clarification in the comments, you want to be able to track the progress on the upload by percentage. *eg. How many % til the upload is finished*

You should check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289637/http-upload-file-progress-in-angularjs) where this has already been discussed.

From the accepted answer:

> I don't think $http.post() can be used for this.
>    As for client-side, it should work with an HTML5 browser, but you'll probably have to create your own XMLHttpRequest object and `onprogress` listener.  See [AngularJS: tracking status of each file being uploaded simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591345/angularjs-tracking-status-of-each-file-being-uploaded-simultaneously) for ideas.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I want a progress bar, not a "Loading" in a Div. Thanks however.

Comment: Do you want to show a [progress bar like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GA9t8/3/)? Or do you want to display the actual progress, % bytes/total sent to the server? @ZioBudda

Comment: The 2nd: I need to display %bytes/total (in a progress bar). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the eventHandlers of the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

like:

```
mainModule.service('File', function (Api) {

    var controller = 'files';

    function File(data) {
        this.$data = data;
    }

    File.__proto__ = File.prototype = {
        upload: function (progress) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', this.$data);
            return pack('/upload').post(fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                uploadEventHandlers: {'progress': progress},
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            });
        }
    };

    return File;
    function pack(action) {
        return Api(controller + action);
    }
});
```

Api is a service to connect with the server api.

$data is the file object from the input

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write show hide in every single http method, then we can create a simple directive by using `$http.pendingRequests.length` and and that's it.

Whenever we will have any http request in progress it will be showing automatically.

```
app.directive('loading', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
                if (v) {
                    elm.show();
                } else {
                    elm.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

AND HTML

```
 <div data-loading>
   Please wait...
 </div>
```

[For more detail see this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1184/angularjs-progress-bar-directive-for-entire-application)